how to add configmap without change permission on parent directory inside a deployment.yaml
I have an Openshift deployment and I need to add a config file in a certain path.
I mount these volumes
    volumes:
    - name: empty-vol
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: cics-config-volume
      configMap:
        name: cics-conf

in this way
    volumeMounts:
    - name: cics-config-volume
      mountPath: /workspace/project/src/main/liberty/config/
    - name: empty-vol
      mountPath: /workspace/project/

And I can find a configuration file inside the mounthpath dir but after if the application tries to copy a new file in a parent directory such as
/workspace/project/src/main/api
than the application gets "Permission Denied"
How to avoid "Permission Denied"?

Have you tried using subPath? https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.15/nodes/containers/nodes-containers-volumes.html#nodes-containers-volumes-subpath_nodes-containers-volumes

yes I tried but it doesn't work
